# Subgrid with a FooterRow

Tags: jqgrid, footer, subgrid

Is it possible to set to a jqGrid subgrid a footerrow. I have a mainGrid that contains many rows and every row have a subgrid.
Or must I use the Master-Details way to do this like [here ("Advanced" -> "Master Detail")](http://www.trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html)

The Grid should looks like this:

```
       |   Col1   |   Col2    |   Col3
_______|__________|___________|___________________________
   -   | value1   | value 2   | 10
       |__________|___________|___________________________
       |   Subgrid col1   |   Subgrid col2   |  Subcol3
       |__________________|__________________|___________
       |   subgridvalue1  |   subgridvalue2  |  15
       |__________________|__________________|___________
       |another subridval1|another subridval2|  5
       |__________________|__________________|___________
       |                  |      Totals:     |  20
_______|__________________|__________________|___________
   +   |oter value|oter value2| 12
_______|__________|___________|___________________________
footer:|          | Totals:   | 22
```

I hope you can understand what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you would use [Subgrid as Grid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3asubgrid_as_grid) you will be able to have any elements in the subgrids inclusive `footerrow` option.